# Quotes encoded in url

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to call this url
`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=startswith(displayName,'Matteo')`

This is my typescript/angular code:

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class EmployeeService {
  baseurl: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.baseurl = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users';

  }

  search(term: string) {
    const url = this.baseurl + "?$filter=startswith(displayName,'" + term + "')&select=employeeId&mailNickname";
    return this.http.get(url).subscribe(response => console.log(response));
  }
```

But I have this error:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=startswith(displayName,%27Matteo%27)&select=employeeId&mailNickname 403 (Forbidden)
```

The problem is that the quotes are encoded.
Any suggestion?

Thanks

UPDATE:
Sorry, my fault, it was a problem in azure configurations.
The url is fine also with the quotes escaped (%27%).

Comment: you receive a 403 code, looks like the method you are trying to access in the API is not available for some reason, are you sure that the url is correct?

Comment: So it was solved?

Comment: yes, it was solved. 
I was thinking of deleting the post but it seems we shouldn't